# Минимальная версия Windows на которой будет работать .NET CORE 5.0

Tags: .net, .net-core

Подскажите, а какая минимальная версия Windows, где будет работать .NET CORE 5.0?

Что-то искал искал и не нашел матрицу...

Comment: Замечание. "поддерживается" не то же самое, что "работает". На Server 2008 R2 все ещё работает, хотя в табличке минимальная поддерживаемая версия 2012 R2

Comment: @vitidev интересно, а в IIS'е он норм будет хостится в Server 2008 R2, там же какой-то пакет доп. ставить надо